# Difference between this 2 values?

Tags: solidity, web3js

In my js file I call a send transaction to the smart contract, so what is the difference between values :

`instance.multiply.sendTransaction(val,{ from: accounts[0], gas : 300000}` and `instance.multiply.sendTransaction({ from: accounts[0], gas : 30000, value : val}`,

I am passing first one to the function as an argument and the second is accessible in the function just by `msg.value` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first code snippet, you're passing `val` as an argument to a function.

In the second code snippet, you're not passing any arguments, but you're sending `val` wei in the transaction. Yes, the contract, can see how much wei was sent by looking at `msg.value`, but importantly there was also a transfer of ether. (10**18 wei == 1 ether.)

So the key differences between the two are:

1. One passes a value as an argument, and the other doesn't.
2. One sends some ether with the transaction, and the other doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

> Proper Syntax for web3.eth.sendTransaction

```
 web3.eth.sendTransaction(transactionObject [, callback])
```

Second one works fine `instance.multiply.sendTransaction({ from: accounts[0], gas : 30000, value : val},` and should.

The format of sendTransaction is `sendTransaction({from: eth.accounts[0], data: code, gas: 100000})`.

1. `from:` String - The address for the sending account. Uses the
   web3.eth.defaultAccount property, if not specified.
2. `to:` String - (**optional**) The destination address of the message,
   left undefined for a contract-creation transaction.
3. `value:` Number|String|BigNumber - (**optional**) The value transferred
   for the transaction in Wei, also the endowment if it's a
   contract-creation transaction.
4. `gas:` Number|String|BigNumber - (**optional**, default:
   To-Be-Determined) The amount of gas to use for the transaction
   (*unused gas is refunded*).
5. `data`: String - (**optional**) Either a byte string containing the
   associated data of the message, or in the case of a
   contract-creation transaction, the initialisation code.

For more See: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendtransaction